# How to Strip html tags using mysql triggers / Stored procedures

Tags: mysql

I have the following MYSQL Trigger that stores data into MySQL table but currently it is storing html and css tags as well, how can I remove all html and css tags before storing the data to MySQL? below is what I have so far.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tickets BEFORE INSERT ON tickets_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.CUSTOMER_ID = 'NULL' THEN
SET NEW.CUSTOMER_ID = (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM clients_table WHERE    
CUSTOMER_EMAIL=NEW.CUSTOMER_EMAIL);
END IF;
END
```

So this stores data correctly, just need to strip tags that is being stored into tickets_data column

Comment: Why not [strip_tags](http://pk1.php.net/strip_tags) before inserting or updating them using php?

Comment: I cannot do that as I am using a software to connect to MySQL and insert data. no php in involved here

Comment: Well, what about the "software" that's connecting to your MySQL instance? What is it? Maybe that can remove the tags before the trigger fires?

Comment: The software is by GeniusConnect, http://www.geniusconnect.com/ and so far I don't see an option to strip tags.

Comment: they have Html Body support that outputs plain text but I would like to exclude <p><b><br> and div tags. anyway to do this with MySQL trigger and stored procedures?